# Disable button once clicked - Odoo v8

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def account_move_sc5_10(self):
    #if record.state in ('awaitingraw'):
    for record in self:
        #if record.state in ('draft'):
        tempy = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles - record.contract_worksheet.total_totals
        acc_move = self.env['account.move'] 
        move_lines = [
            (0, 0, {
                'name': 'name', # a label so accountant can understand where this line come from
                'debit': tempy or 0.0, # amount of debit
                'credit': 0, # amount of credit
                'account_id': record.transporter.transp_transit.id, #account_id, # account 
                'date': fields.Date.today(), #date,
                'partner_id': record.transporter.id, # partner if there is one
                #'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
            }),
            (0, 0, {
                'name': 'name',
                'debit': 0, 
                'credit': record.contract_worksheet.total_alles or 0.0,
                'account_id': record.transporter.transp_transit.id,
                #'analytic_account_id': context.get('analytic_id', False),
                'date': fields.Date.today(), #date,
                'partner_id': record.transporter.id,
                #'currency_id': currency_id or (account.currency_id.id or False),
            })
        ]

        journal_id = False
        if record.transporter.transp_transit:
            journals = self.env['account.journal'].search([
                ('default_debit_account_id', '=', record.transporter.transp_transit.id)
            ])
            if journals:
                journal_id = journals[0].id
                acc_move.create({
                #'period_id': period_id, #Fiscal period
                    'journal_id': journal_id, #self.aajournal.id, # journal ex: sale journal, cash journal, bank journal....
                    'date': fields.Date.today(),
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'line_id': move_lines, # this is one2many field to account.move.line
                })
```

Which I call from view like this `<button string="Account Moves" name="account_move_sc5_10" states="awaitingraw" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>`

I need that once this button is clicked, it should remain readonly, I know that with a boolean it could be done, but with this `account.move` method I'm kinda confused on how to achieve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not possible to make the button be disabled with `attrs` and `readonly` (https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/13264). If you don't mind, you could do it invisible after the click. If you want it to be visible but disabled, it'd be a bit more tricky, because you'd need to add a CSS class to your module.

Comment: Right, well, I'll try making it invisible... Going to search for some example, do You know about some? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If making the button invisible after clicking on the button is OK for you, you can do this:

Declare a field in the model where the button method is:

```
button_clicked = fields.Boolean(
    string='Button clicked',
    default=False,
)
```

Modify the method called by the button, just to add this line:

```
@api.multi
def account_move_sc5_10(self):
    for record in self:
        record.write({
            'button_clicked': True,
        })
        ...
```

Modify the view of the model where the button belongs to to add the new field and the condition:

```
<field name="button_clicked" invisible="1"/>

<button string="Account Moves" name="account_move_sc5_10" type="object" class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('state', 'not in', 'awaitingraw'), ('button_clicked', '=', True)]}"/>
```

Note that I've removed the `states` parameter and that's because **`attrs` and `states` can't be used together** (they will do nothing if you use both). So, add `state` field to your view if you haven't it.

Comment: simplicity is art. Thanks dear